# c# rock, paper, scissors game and not have a invalid entry output

Tags: c#

While learning C#, I'm working on a rock-paper-scissors game to digest what I've learned, but there's a problem I can't solve. I've thought about it for a while, but I can't figure out what kind of change I can make. I want to be able to receive the 'invalid entry' message when incorrect data is entered. I've written some code related to this, but I don't know where I went wrong, and I can't get the 'invalid entry' message.

```cs
namespace ROCK__PAPER__SCISSOR
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string inputPlayer, inputCPU;
            int randomint;
            
            bool playAgain = true;
            string language;
            Console.Write("CHOOSE LANGUAGE (TR/ENG): \nDİL SEÇ(TR/ENG): "); 
            language = Console.ReadLine();
            language = language.ToUpper();



            while (language == "ENG")
            {
                while (playAgain)
                {
                    int scoreCPU = 0;
                    int scorePlayer = 0;
                    while (scorePlayer < 3 && scoreCPU < 3)
                    {




                        Console.Write("Choose between ROCK, PAPER OR SCISSORS:    ");
                        inputPlayer = Console.ReadLine();
                        inputPlayer = inputPlayer.ToUpper();


                        Random rnd = new Random();
                        randomint = rnd.Next(1, 4);

                        switch (randomint)
                        {
                            case 1:

                                inputCPU = "ROCK";
                                Console.WriteLine("Computer chose ROCK");
                                if (inputPlayer == "ROCK")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("DRAW!!\n\n");
                                }
                                else if (inputPlayer == "PAPER")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("PLAYER WINS!!\n\n");
                                    scorePlayer++;
                                }
                                else if (inputPlayer == "SCISSORS")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("CPU WINS!!\n\n");
                                    scoreCPU++;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                inputCPU = "PAPER";
                                Console.WriteLine("Computer chose PAPER");
                                if (inputPlayer == "PAPER")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("DRAW!!\n\n");
                                }
                                else if (inputPlayer == "ROCK")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("CPU WINS!!\n\n");
                                    scoreCPU++;
                                }
                                else if (inputPlayer == "SCISSORS")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("PLAYER WINS!!\n\n");
                                    scorePlayer++;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                inputCPU = "SCISSORS";
                                Console.WriteLine("Computer chose SCISSORS");
                                if (inputPlayer == "SCISSORS")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("DRAW!!\n\n");
                                }
                                else if (inputPlayer == "ROCK")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("PLAYER WINS!!\n\n");
                                    scorePlayer++;
                                }
                                else if (inputPlayer == "PAPER")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("CPU WINS!!\n\n");
                                    scoreCPU++;
                                }
                                break;
                            `default:
                                Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry!");
                                break;`
                        }
                        
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\nSCORES:\tPLAYER:\t{0}\tCPU:\t{1}", scorePlayer, scoreCPU);
                    }
                    if (scorePlayer == 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("PLAYER WINS!!");
                    }
                    else if (scoreCPU == 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("CPU WINS!!");
                    }
                    Console.Write("Do you wanna play again?(YES/NO): ");
                    string loop1 = Console.ReadLine();
                    loop1 = loop1.ToUpper();
                    if (loop1 == "YES")
                    {
                        playAgain = true;
                        Console.Clear();
                    }
                    else if (loop1 == "NO")
                    {
                        playAgain = false;
                    }



                }

            }

            while (language == "TR")
            {
                while (playAgain)
                {
                    int scoreCPU = 0;
                    int scorePlayer = 0;
                    while (scorePlayer < 3 && scoreCPU < 3)
                    {




                        Console.Write("TAŞ KAĞIT VE MAKASTAN BİRİNİ SEÇ:    ");
                        inputPlayer = Console.ReadLine();
                        inputPlayer = inputPlayer.ToUpper();


                        Random rnd = new Random();
                        randomint = rnd.Next(1, 4);

                        switch (randomint)
                        {
                            case 1:

                                inputCPU = "TAŞ";
                                Console.WriteLine("BİLGİSAYAR TAŞ SEÇTİ");
                                if (inputPlayer == "TAŞ")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("BERABERE!!\n\n");
                                }
                                else if (inputPlayer == "KAĞIT")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("KAZANDIN!!\n\n");
                                    scorePlayer++;
                                }
                                else if (inputPlayer == "MAKAS")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("KAYBETTİN!!\n\n");
                                    scoreCPU++;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                inputCPU = "KAĞIT";
                                Console.WriteLine("BİLGİSAYAR KAĞIT SEÇTİ");
                                if (inputPlayer == "KAĞIT")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("BERABERE!!\n\n");
                                }
                                else if (inputPlayer == "TAŞ")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("KAYBETTİN!!\n\n");
                                    scoreCPU++;
                                }
                                else if (inputPlayer == "MAKAS")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("KAZANDIN!!\n\n");
                                    scorePlayer++;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                inputCPU = "MAKAS";
                                Console.WriteLine("BİLGİSAYAR MAKAS SEÇTİ");
                                if (inputPlayer == "MAKAS")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("BERABERE!!\n\n");
                                }
                                else if (inputPlayer == "TAŞ")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("KAZANDIN!!\n\n");
                                    scorePlayer++;
                                }
                                else if (inputPlayer == "KAĞIT")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("KAYBETTİN!!\n\n");
                                    scoreCPU++;
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                Console.WriteLine("Yanlış veri girdiniz!");
                                break;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\nSKOR:\tSEN:\t{0}\tBİLGİSAYAR:\t{1}", scorePlayer, scoreCPU);
                    }

                    if (scorePlayer == 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("OYUNU KAZANDIN!!");
                    }
                    else if (scoreCPU == 3)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("OYUNU KAYBETTİN!!");
                    }
                    Console.Write("Tekrar oynamak ister misin?(EVET/HAYIR): ");
                    string loop=Console.ReadLine();
                    loop = loop.ToUpper();
                    if (loop =="EVET") 
                    {
                        playAgain = true;
                        Console.Clear();
                    }
                    else if (loop == "HAYIR")
                    {
                        playAgain = false;
                    }



                }

            }
```

Comment: The error cannot happen, since the `default` case is only used when the random number returns something other than 1,2, or 3, so if the CPU tries to cheat. This isn't going to happen. You should refactor the input and assign the player input to a separate variable before the switch statement. Generally, your code contains far to many redundancies.

Comment: You need to learn reading documentation with understanding from `Random.Next(i32,i32)`  docs: *maxValue - 
**The exclusive** upper bound of the random number returned. maxValue must be greater than or equal to minValue.*

Answer (score 0):

You switch cpu input (should be 1-3). `default:` means if CPUinput is not 1 or 2 or 3 then run "invalid input". But this make no sense. Just loop request user input is all right. I modify the English part code with comment `"//modified"`

```
string inputPlayer, inputCPU;
int randomint;

bool playAgain = true;
string language;
Console.Write("CHOOSE LANGUAGE (TR/ENG): \nDİL SEÇ(TR/ENG): ");
language = Console.ReadLine();
language = language.ToUpper();



while (language == "ENG")
{
    while (playAgain)
    {
        int scoreCPU = 0;
        int scorePlayer = 0;
        while (scorePlayer < 3 && scoreCPU < 3) 
        {


            while (true)    //modified loop to ask for userinput until valid
            {
                Console.Write("Choose between ROCK, PAPER OR SCISSORS:    ");
                inputPlayer = Console.ReadLine();
                inputPlayer = inputPlayer.ToUpper();

                if (inputPlayer=="ROCK"|| inputPlayer == "ROCK"|| inputPlayer == "ROCK")
                { break; }

                Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry!");
            }







            Random rnd = new Random();
            randomint = rnd.Next(1, 3);  //modified  1-3

            switch (randomint)
            {
                case 1:

                    inputCPU = "ROCK";
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose ROCK");
                    if (inputPlayer == "ROCK")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("DRAW!!\n\n");
                    }
                    else if (inputPlayer == "PAPER")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("PLAYER WINS!!\n\n");
                        scorePlayer++;
                    }
                    else if (inputPlayer == "SCISSORS")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("CPU WINS!!\n\n");
                        scoreCPU++;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    inputCPU = "PAPER";
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose PAPER");
                    if (inputPlayer == "PAPER")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("DRAW!!\n\n");
                    }
                    else if (inputPlayer == "ROCK")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("CPU WINS!!\n\n");
                        scoreCPU++;
                    }
                    else if (inputPlayer == "SCISSORS")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("PLAYER WINS!!\n\n");
                        scorePlayer++;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    inputCPU = "SCISSORS";
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose SCISSORS");
                    if (inputPlayer == "SCISSORS")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("DRAW!!\n\n");
                    }
                    else if (inputPlayer == "ROCK")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("PLAYER WINS!!\n\n");
                        scorePlayer++;
                    }
                    else if (inputPlayer == "PAPER")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("CPU WINS!!\n\n");
                        scoreCPU++;
                    }
                    break;   //modified delete default: situation.

                        }

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nSCORES:\tPLAYER:\t{0}\tCPU:\t{1}", scorePlayer, scoreCPU);
        }
        if (scorePlayer == 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PLAYER WINS!!");
        }
        else if (scoreCPU == 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CPU WINS!!");
        }
        Console.Write("Do you wanna play again?(YES/NO): ");
        string loop1 = Console.ReadLine();
        loop1 = loop1.ToUpper();
        if (loop1 == "YES")
        {
            playAgain = true;
            Console.Clear();
        }
        else if (loop1 == "NO")
        {
            playAgain = false;
        }



    }

}
```